# celery app.delay() is keep on waiting for the response, not working

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

I am trying to experiment with celery with Redis broker in my Django application, but I am having a hard time getting it write can anyone point me where I am missing things

my **init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app', )
```

my base_settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

my celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
app = Celery('myapp')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.conf.enable_utc = False
app.conf.update(timezone='Asia/Kolkata', task_always_eager=True)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

In my views.py

```
@app.task(name="test celery")
def add(a, b):
    print(a, b, a + b)


@api_view(['GET'])
def testcelery(request):
    a = request.GET.get('a', 0)
    b = request.GET.get('b', 0)
    add.delay(a, b)
    return Response({"status": "ok"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

the output of my celery worker

```
>celery -A lylo worker --loglevel=info -c 5
 -------------- celery@LAPTOP-VQHQANA1 v5.1.1 (sun-harmonics)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 2021-09-08 22:00:46
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         lylo:0x289e11010b8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 5 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . myapp.celery.debug_task
  . test celery

[2021-09-08 22:00:47,585: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 6672 calling self.run()
[2021-09-08 22:00:47,585: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 33680 calling self.run()
[2021-09-08 22:00:47,601: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 36712 calling self.run()
[2021-09-08 22:00:47,629: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 21636 calling self.run()
[2021-09-08 22:00:47,689: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 27176 calling self.run()
[2021-09-08 22:00:49,002: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2021-09-08 22:00:51,021: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-09-08 22:00:58,046: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2021-09-08 22:01:08,068: WARNING/MainProcess] d:\installed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:204: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  leak, never use this setting in production environments!''')

[2021-09-08 22:01:08,071: INFO/MainProcess] celery@LAPTOP-VQHQANA1 ready.
```

my redis-cli monitor
[image: my redis monitor]

in my redis-cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox"
2) "_kombu.binding.celery"
3) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
4) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
```

but when I send a request its not returning any output instead, its keep on waiting for the response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You setted `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`, this makes celery tasks to be executed locally instead of being sent to the queue. See https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_always_eager .

The response of the request is empty because you are returning implicitly `None` on your view.

To send tasks to the queue, set `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False` or just remove it (default value is `False`).

Comment: 1. The response of the request is empty because you are returning implicitly None on your view.:  I mean, it's waiting for the response, note that I have added "return Response({"status": "ok"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)" it's still waiting for the response

2.  set CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False: did this but still same

Comment: @krishna are you able to access any other endpoint? Do you have any log on your django server? That you keep waiting for the response doesn't seems to be related with celery.

Comment: if i remove .delay() from this line add.delay(a, b) it works fine

Comment: what you used instead?